# How do i restrict my app to ios 10 devices only ?

Tags: iphone, xcode8, ios10

On xcode 8 the latest deployment target is 9.1 and that includes iphone 4S but i only want to release it on iphone 5 and above. Please help. Thanks

Comment: Use Xcode 8.3.2, set the iOS Deployment Target to 10.0

Comment: I'm using Xcode 8.3.2, the latest here is 9.1. Theres no 10

Comment: I want iphone 5 and above. The reason why i added ios 10 devices is because ios 10 is not available on iphone 4S